# prisma filtering with contains

Tags: javascript, mongodb, orm, prisma, prisma2

is there any way where we pass "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" and find if a string exists in a specific database column with "https://stackoverflow.com"? basically finding a string in a database column that matches a part of the input string. opposite of the `contains` filter where we check if the database column with a value contains an input string

these are the example input combinations that I wanted to try:

```
https://prisma.io/docs/
https://prisma.io/docs/reference/
https://prisma.io/about
https://prisma.io/contact
https://stackoverflow.com/about
https://stackoverflow.com/contact
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

output: it should return a column that contains `https://prisma.io` or `https://stackoverflow.com` based on input string

Comment: Is it always the host part that you want to look for? Then you could manipulate the string before querying...

Comment: Column values can be used as LIKE operator's pattern. e.g. `SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask' LIKE CONCAT('%', url, '%');` . Does it fit your situation? It requires you to use queryRaw though.